# RecyclerView with GridView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview, listview-adapter

Once I write a `ListView` demo, the `ListView`'s items have some different types.

item1:

Text

Pic Pic Pic

Pic Pic Pic

item2:

Text

Pic Pic

Pic Pic

item3:

Text

Pic Pic Pic

Pic Pic Pic

Pic Pic Pic

...

So I `override` the `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()`.It work well.
But Now I change to use `RecyclerView`. Is there a better solution?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
getItemCount() {
//pojo class array size
 return mDataset.size();
}
```

Comment: please upvote if u like this , call your array of pojo class and get instance of it and count by size  private ArrayList<PojoClass> mDataset; in your Adapterclass

Comment: You might misunderstand what I mean.

Comment: Could you explain your code? Code-only answers are generally not acceptable on StackOverflow, and as such are liable to be deleted.

Comment: @RajeshJadav the question asked by him was how to get item from the list so based on the question i have passed

Answer (score 0):

This is sample, you can create an item view with a textview and nonscrolling gridview

```
public class NonScrollGridView extends GridView {

    public NonScrollGridView (Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NonScrollGridView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public NonScrollGridView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // Do not use the highest two bits of Integer.MAX_VALUE because they are
        // reserved for the MeasureSpec mode
        int heightSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightSpec);
        getLayoutParams().height = getMeasuredHeight();


    }
}
```

Your RecyclerView item view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"/> 

    <com.example.NonScrollGridView 
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thx,but it not good when the NonScrollGridView recycling. So I extends LinearLayout.

Comment: @EgosZhang you mean you don't want the item be recycled? so what's the point you use recyclerview?

Comment: NonScrollGridView extends GridView your code doesn't work well when scroll.

Comment: @EgosZhang OK, I see your point. If you have any other questions just let me know.