# Recyclerview with multiple dynamic types view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a questions about `Recyclerview` when the types of items are dynamic.It means I don't know how many types of `Recyclerview`'s items.So I don't know how to write the `onCreateViewHolder()` in `MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adpter<RecylerView.ViewHolder>`.

But in fact, the items follow some laws.For example:

item1:

```
Text(title)
Pic(Vertical) Pic(Vertical) Pic(Vertical)
Pic(Vertical) Pic(Vertical) Pic(Vertical)
```

item2:

```
Text(title)
Pic(Horizontal) Pic(Horizontal)
Pic(Horizontal) Pic(Horizontal)
```

If the picture is Vertical,the column is three.If the picture is Horizontal,the column is two.And the num of pictures maybe one,two,three,four,five,six and so on,So the types I can't confirm.
I am sorry because I can't show a picture.I have ask a question [RecyclerView with GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860660/recyclerview-with-gridview)

But it doesn't solve my questions.I have see [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

But the types are unchanged.
PS:I know the pictures are vertical or Horizontal from data.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you create two custom ViewHolder's and check which one is passing into onCreateviewHolder as seen in this answer? [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

class ViewHolder0 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
   //viewHolder for horitzontal pics
    ...
}

class ViewHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
    //viewHolder for vertical pics
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    // Just as an example, return 0 or 2 depending on position
    // Note that unlike in ListView adapters, types don't have to be contiguous
    return position % 2 * 2;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     switch (viewType) {
         case 0: return new ViewHolder0(...);
         case 2: return new ViewHolder2(...);
         ...
     }
}
```

}

In [docs](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/material/lists-cards.html/index.html) you have the way to extend RecyclerView.ViewHolder

```
// Provide a reference to the views for each data item
// Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
// you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    // each data item is just a string in this case
    public TextView mTextView;
    public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
        super(v);
        mTextView = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: How's the data you want to bind in onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) Here you can just make a for and loop through the images you are getting

Comment: Where I write a for and loop through the images I am getting? Are you sure you know the meaning of my question ?

Comment: In adapter constructor i assume your getting your data: views, pics... 
In your onCreateViewHolder you can switch from viewHolders, 
And in onCreateViewHolder you can loop through the data from your constuctor atributes and add views to viewHolder programatically 
(ViewGroup) view.addView()  http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View, int, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)